# Proxy path with deep nested url

Tags: nginx

I have server with running app - manictime.
I want redirect nested url that send back images.

So now I trying delete **thumbnail** from path.

/analytics/timelines/screenshot/50699baf-9b4a-4b72-a755-c9b2346a7fc238/1/a5aa2a4c-65d3-4c91-81a9-34cbef22d667/2020-04-02/2020-04-02_19-44-12_03-00_2560_1057_132917.**thumbnail**.jpg

https://regex101.com/r/sM3eS9/4
example how regexp works.

But I can't make it work in NginX.

```
        server {
            listen        80;
            server_name   manictime.tech.fun;
            location / {
                proxy_pass         http://localhost:8666;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            }

        location ~ ^/analytics/timelines/screenshot/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+).thumbnail.jpg {
                proxy_pass http://localshot:8666/analytics/timelines/screenshot/$1/$2/$3/$4.jpg;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
       }
```

1. What I'm doing wrong?
2. How I can debug nginx redirect?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post your config as text, not as an image.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to achieve with your configuration. You have a `location` which captures the URI to remove the `thumbnail`. Then you put `thumbnail` **back** in the `proxy_pass` statement.

Comment: yeah, it's typo. I try to make it work. But it didn't even in this configuration. I change description - thanks.